# From .ai extension to .ard/.amd/.dxn/.igs using Alphacam. How?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-format

I have a file with .ai extension but need to open it in Alphacam program, which works with extensions like .ard .amd .dxn. igs?

How can I solve this? Do I need to convert the file types, if so, what can I use to convert them?

Comment: Convert it to ard / amd / dxn or igs. Have you searched for a software that does that?

Comment: If you know any which does it, please share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export DXF/DWG files from Illustrator. Go into Illustrator and at the top click on "File", scroll down till you see "Export..". When you click on Eport, you will see your file name, where you want to save it and a button for which format you want to export as. Click on it and a long list will showup and DXF (AutoCAD Interchange File) will be near the top of the list.

[image]

Additionally when you export a file from Illustrator, it will export **EVERYTHING**. Images, vectors that you have turned off, hidden vectors.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Will the main shape (a puzzle in my case) stay the same? No need to fix curves after opening in Alphacam? Wish I could upvote ur post but I need 15 rep. So just accepted your answer.

Comment: Should be pretty accurate. Always check it before producing though. **Remember, measure twice cut once!**